# Show that typical sets satisfy $|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(p)|>|A_\epsilon^{(n)}(q)|$ if $0.5\ge p>q$

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, entropy, compression, typical-sequences

I'm struggling with the following question:
For typical sets in source coding, decide if it is true or false and provide a detailed proof.
[image: question]

[image: Question's Definition]

My ideas:

a. true, since by definition we get 2^log(p) > 2^log(q),
2^(n*H(p)+eps)>? 2^(n*H(q)+eps)
2^(n*(-1/n*log(p)+eps) > 2^(n*(-1/n*log(q)+eps)
p > q, as stated in the question.

b. false, p and q may be not equal, but take p close to q by epsilon, and we might get the same typical set, which yields overlapping.

c. true, since p=1-q, if we take p=1/2 => q=1/2.
and if all values of An(p) are close to An(q), then it's the same set, which means they are the whole {0,1}n

I'm not sure about my answers, would like to hear your thoughts, and proofs if possible.

Comment: can you define what $A_\epsilon(p)^{(n)}$ is?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören
I've added its definition, sorry for the late response

Comment: I don't understand your answer a). Could you elaborate?

Comment: Your answer in $c$ does not make sense. You are mixing three probabilities: The probability that a sequence belongs to $A$ (that tends to 1). The probability of each given sequence. The probability $p$. I'm afraid you have not digested yet the concept of typical sets.

Comment: @leonbloy 
I updated my answers, would like to know your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

By the [AEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property), we know that the size of a typical set satisfies
$$(1-\epsilon) 2^{n(H(X)-\epsilon)} \le |A_\epsilon^{(n)}|\le 2^{n(H(X)+\epsilon)},$$
for large enough $n$. Roughly speaking, we can think this as saying that $|A_\epsilon^{(n)}|\sim 2^{n H(X)}$.

Furthermore, if $0.5\ge p>q$, then $H(p)<H(q)$. The conclusion follows immediately.